# Drawing and making notes with mouse on a pdf during presentation

Tags: beamer, pdf, presentations

I am a teacher who is trying to make instructional videos during the corona lockdown. I want use a presentation for the instruction while recording the screen.

I use latex beamer for my presentations and I would like to use my mouse to make certain notes on the slides during the presentation as a replacement of my whiteboard in the classroom.

Microsoft PowerPoint has a built-in pen feature that allows the use of the mouse as a pen during a presentation. However, I refuse to use Powerpoint since the typesetting for equations and formulas is terrible.

Is there a way to draw on beamer/PDF slides during a presentation?

I am a Windows 10 and Linux Mint user.

Comment: Hello @mart and welcome to the TeX-community! I think your question is off-topic here, since it's not related to LaTeX. I would suggest you to post the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can still use PowerPoint just to present the pdf slides, can't you? It is not very convenient but you can copy the slides into your PowerPoint presentation and present them in the usual way. If you have a tablet, you can annotate the pdf with the usual means, e.g. Acrobat Reader on an iPad allows you to draw on the pdf.

Comment: Did the above comments solve your problem mart ?

Comment: More off topic, but have you tried PPT more recently? The equation tool now mostly accepts amsmath/LaTeX syntax. E.g write \alpha and press space gives you the Greek alpha symbol. Not suggesting to change your workflow just to reevaluate if the original reason you chose for software A over software B are still valid.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is offtopic

Comment: I use xournalapp for this. Definitely runs on linux, might even be cross-platform now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I discovered that, in Adobe Reader, once you are in full screen mode, you can press `Shift+D` seven times until you get a *pencil* cursor that you can use to draw on your slides. You need to ensure that *Edit → Preferences → General → Basic Tools → [x] Use single-key accelerators to access tools* is checked off under preferences. There are full instructions here: cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society

Comment: Not funny at all

Answer (score 1):

PdfPresenter works if you install java 8. Currently, I tested it, and works fine. You can make text annotations, marker, and pencil highlights and zoom.